# ModuleNotFoundError extract_msg

Tags: python, pip, module

Im trying to use the extract_msg module and It return ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extract_msg'.
I have installed pip and extract_msg. Could anyone help me to point out where the issue could be?

Many thanks.

Im expecting to solve this issue.

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: @jeril yes Im using windows. I have tried uninstall and install it via terminal.

Comment: it is working fine for me in my windows machine, is it installed correctly in your machine?